# Dataweave, How to remove the extra \n when generating a csv?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am generating a csv file to be sent to a SFTP location.
The file is created as expected except by the extra \n
is there anyway to remove it?

Input:

```
[
    {
        "reference": "TPL",
        "newId": "07223455",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    },
    {
        "reference": "TIN",
        "newId": "07123455",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    },
    {
        "reference": "THW",
        "newId": "05550910",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    },
    {
        "reference": "THW",
        "newId": "05533112",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    },
    {
        "reference": "TSB",
        "newId": "05567865",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    }
]
```

Dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header = false
import * from dw::core::Strings
---
payload filter ( $.error == '000' ) map (
    values:
       rightPad($.reference, 16)
    ++ rightPad('0', 1)
    ++ rightPad($.newId, 9)
    ++ rightPad('0', 1)
    ++ rightPad($.dateCreated,9)
    ++ rightPad("", 16)
    ++ rightPad("P",1)
    ++ rightPad("", 103)
 )
```

Result:

```
TPL             07223455  020200509                 P                                                                                                       
TIN             07123455  020200509                 P                                                                                                       
THW             05550910  020200509                 P                                                                                                       
THW             05533112  020200509                 P                                                                                                       
TSB             05567865  020200709                 P                                                                                                       
TSB             05533112  020200509                 P
```

I tried remove the last line

```
result[0 to sizeOf(result) -1]
```

but the \n is added at the end of each line by default

Comment: Can you provide input data?

Comment: Are you having issues with the target system not liking the trailing line?

Comment: I am not sure whether what you are generating is CSV, I think it looks more like a flat-file or better fixed-width.  When I get a little extra time I 'll do it for you. Maybe you need to reconsider your output media-type

Comment: @MichaelJones yes, the target system cannot read the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/flatfile schemaPath="schema.ffd"
var data = [
    {
        "reference": "TPL",
        "newId": "07223455",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    },
    {
        "reference": "TIN",
        "newId": "07123455",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    },
    {
        "reference": "THW",
        "newId": "05550910",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    },
    {
        "reference": "THW",
        "newId": "05533112",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    },
    {
        "reference": "TSB",
        "newId": "05567865",
        "dateCreated": "020200509",
        "error": "000"
    }
]
---
data map {($ - "error"), p: "P"}
```

You have to create a file under your classpath (I created it under `src/main/resources`) containing the schema, I called it `schema.ffd` and you can see its contents below:

```
form: FIXEDWIDTH
name: my-flat-file
values:
- { name: 'reference', type: String, length: 16 }
- { name: 'newId', type: String, length: 10 }
- { name: 'dateCreated', type: String, length: 25 }
- { name: 'p', type: String, length: 104 }
```

I get the following as an output:

```
TPL             07223455  020200509                P                                                                                                       
TIN             07123455  020200509                P                                                                                                       
THW             05550910  020200509                P                                                                                                       
THW             05533112  020200509                P                                                                                                       
TSB             05567865  020200509                P
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always do this:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
import * from dw::core::Strings
---
write(payload filter ( $.error == '000' ) map (
    values:
       rightPad($.reference, 16)
    ++ rightPad('0', 1)
    ++ rightPad($.newId, 9)
    ++ rightPad('0', 1)
    ++ rightPad($.dateCreated,9)
    ++ rightPad("", 16)
    ++ rightPad("P",1)
    ++ rightPad("", 103)
 ), "application/csv", { header: false})[0 to -2]
```

Edit to include turning off the header.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my workaround.  I'm not thrilled with it, because it prevents streaming the input... but it does truncate the trailing line feed!

On unix-like systems:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
var csvSerialized = write(payload, "application/csv")
---
csvSerialized[0 to -2]
```

On windows, there is a carriage return and a line feed. So you have to truncate two:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
var csvSerialized = write(payload, "application/csv")
---
csvSerialized[0 to -3]
```

This cross platform solution works in a Mule runtime, courtesy of Tony DeFusco!

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
var numNewlineChars = sizeOf(Mule::p("line.separator"))
var csvSerialized = write(payload, "application/csv")
---
csvSerialized[0 to -(numNewlineChars + 1)]
```